# Problems trying to configure Ecrire with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to configure Ecrire with my postgresql database, but I keep running into this error whenever I input `psql -d postgres`.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I just don't know how to fix this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the database running?

```
ps auxwf | grep postgres
```

It's also possible that the socket file is in another directory, or the database is listening on another port. Can you post the values "unix_socket_directories" and "port" from your postgresql.conf file?